# Change input field values using a variable for 'name'

Tags: jquery, variables, input-field

I understand using  `$('input[name="_"']).val('');`will replace an input field by name.

I want to use a loop to cycle through a range of names. `$('input[name="'variable_name'"']).val('');` results in an error saying the line is missing a closing bracket `')'`.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You need to add `+` for string concatenation `$('input[name="' + variable_name + '"']).val('');`

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Thanks Alon!

Answer (score 1):

In javascript you need to add `+` to concatenate strings, and the jquery selector requires a string. The solution would thus be:

```
$('input[name="'+variable_name+'"]').val(''); //Note the addition of the 2 + signs
```

You also misplaced a single quote at the end (before the `]` instead of after)